# PHP MySQL insertion not working

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

I am trying to insert data into phpmyadmin. I am kinda new to this. I am trying to insert data with an HTML form. I have the following HTML code:

```
<form id = "vraagStellen" action = "shoutbox.php" method = "post" class = "col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 form-inline" role="form">
    <div class = "selectAfbeelding form-group">
        <label for "selectAfb">Naam:</label><br />
        <input type = "text" id = "selectAfb" name = "selectAfb" class = "form-control" maxlength="30"><br />
    </div>
    <div class = "selectVraag form-group">
        <label for "vraag">Bericht:</label><br />
        <input type = "text" id = "vraag" name = "vraag" class = "form-control" maxlength="100">
    </div>
    <br />
        <input type="reset" name = "reset" value = "Opnieuw" id = "reset">
        <input type="submit" name = "verzend" value = "Verzenden" id = "verzenden">
</form>
```

And the PHP:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".localhost.";dbname=".dbname, dbuser, dbpass);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
$afbeelding = $_POST['selectAfb'];
$question = $_POST['vraag'];

$sql3 = "INSERT INTO `dbi286018`.`vraagstellen` (`id`, `Afbeelding`, `Vraag`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, :afbeelding, :question, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
//Prepare your query
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql3);
//Execute your query binding variables
$stmt->execute(array(':id'=>NULL, ':Afbeelding'=>$afbeelding, ':Vraag'=>$question));
```

Comment: What errors are you getting @Rubenxfd

Comment: You won't need to insert A `NULL` value for the id part. Additionally you are mixing the Vraag (dutch) and question (english) part.

Comment: 'Vraag' is the column in my db

Comment: your binds don't match and for a few reasons. Having checked for errors, would have told you that. Start by reading the manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: we allso have no idea where these are assigned `dbname, dbuser, dbpass` or if it's just a representation of.

Answer (score 0):

If you don`t want to insert value into db you can just omit it.
You should use for example now() to enter current time, or date() function or default field type from mySQL db itself.

```
    $sql3 = "INSERT INTO `dbi286018`.`vraagstellen`
 (`Afbeelding`, `Vraag`, `date`) VALUES (:afbeelding, :question, now());";
```

The placeholder :question / :afbeelding, have to match binding names below, and you have to bind all your variables to placeholders:

```
  //Execute your query binding variables
    $stmt->execute(array(':Afbeelding'=>$afbeelding, ':question'=>$question));
```

I always prefer to build make queries like below, it`s easier for read:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `dbi286018`.`vraagstellen`
   (`Afbeelding`, `Vraag`, `date`) VALUES (:afbeelding, :question, now()");

$sth->bindParam(':afbeelding', $afbeelding);
$sth->bindParam(':question', $question);
$sth->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comment, you are mixing vraag and question in your query (see the last line).

```
$sql3 = "INSERT INTO `dbi286018`.`vraagstellen` (`id`, `Afbeelding`, `Vraag`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, :afbeelding, :question, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
//Prepare your query
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql3);
//Execute your query binding variables
$stmt->execute(array(':id'=>NULL, ':Afbeelding'=>$afbeelding, ':question'=>$question));
```