# Get MySQL ID from loaded table with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, html-table

I am trying to get the ID from a specific table row when I click on it. I have the following PHP code:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, eventName, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y'), time, aantal_spelers, current_spelers FROM dutch_delight ORDER BY date, time";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);



                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "<tr><td>".$row["DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y')"]."</td>"."<td>".$row["time"]."</td>"."<td>".$row["eventName"]."</td>"."<td>".$row["aantal_spelers"]."</td>"."<td>".$row["current_spelers"]."</td></tr>";
                    }

                } 

                else {
                    echo "Er zijn nog geen evenementen aangemaakt.";
                }
```

Now, What I want to do is when I click on a specific table row it will alert the ID of this row. So if there are 30 rows and I click the 10th one, I need to display the correct ID. Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: *"Does anyone have an idea?"* - Idea on what; on if your code is failing or how to do it? You also tagged as jQuery, *why?*

Comment: On how to do it. This code is loading everything correctly.

Comment: Have you tried to figure it out yourself first? If so and your code failed, show us what you tried.

Comment: For this question it doesn't really matter that you've pulled the data out of a  database; not even that you're using php to create the html output the client reads. It's just about a client-side onClick handler that, based on the source object, fetches some other data.

Comment: Plus, in seeing your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/33417178/ we have no idea whether or not you're still using PDO to connect/query with. So, your question is both "too broad" and "unclear".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 echo "<tr onclick=\"alert('".$row['ID']."')\"><td>".$row["DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y')"]."</td>"."<td>".$row["time"]."</td>"."<td>".$row["eventName"]."</td>"."<td>".$row["aantal_spelers"]."</td>"."<td>".$row["current_spelers"]."</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery/javascript for this

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<tr onclick=\"alert('".$row['ID']."')\"><td>".$row["DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y')"]."</td>"."<td>".$row["time"]."</td>"."<td>".$row["eventName"]."</td>"."<td>".$row["aantal_spelers"]."</td>"."<td>".$row["current_spelers"]."</td></tr>";
                }
```

Here use onclick event on TR to alert the Ids.every row has their own ID whenever you click on the table row corresponding ID will pop-up.

Comment: i think it should be `$row["ID"]` and not the `time`

Answer (score 0):

in your while you need to give for any rows a id

```
echo '<tr id="'.$row['ID'].'"><td>......</td></tr>';
```

and including in your file the javascript

```
<script>
var table = document.querySelector('table');

table.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
    var theID = ev.target.id;
    alert(theID);
})
</script>
```